# Implement latitude and longitude in mapbox locationcomponent

Tags: location, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I want to add Latlng or Point inside locationcomponent function in mapbox. How can I add this.
I am using android studio and java.

```
            LatLng latboy1 = new LatLng(23, 90);
            Point origin1 =Point.fromLngLat(34,32);
            
            locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(
                    LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(this, loadedMapStyle)
                            .build());
```